# Imagemagick - draw shape relative to another shapes position

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec

In Imagemagick is it possible to draw a shape or text and place it relative to another shapes position instead of the canvas relative position.

I won't know the size of each shape.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean the repage option? http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#repage

Comment: Hmm possibly. Any idea if there are examples of it's usage?

Comment: So repage works on setting the canvas position in the center of the previous shape drawn.  It is possible to use gravity in repage? Say I wanted the second shape to be drawn immediately to the left or right of the previous shape.